# launch failed: Remote "snapcraft" is unknown or unreachable - multipass returned exit code 2

Tags: snap, multipass

I was learning how to create snaps by following [tutorial on Ubuntu's website](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-your-first-snap#3-building-a-snap-is-easy). The first three steps went great but just as I was going to get to the forth I needed to go somewhere. The next day I'm trying to continue and nothing works.

When trying to run `snapcraft` I'm getting

```
❯ snapcraft -v
Starting Snapcraft 7.3.1                                                                                                                                                 
Logging execution to '~/.local/state/snapcraft/log/snapcraft-20230321-191401.108439.log'                                                                       
Launching a VM.
Build environment is in unknown state, cleaning first.
info failed: The following errors occurred:
instance "snapcraft-my-snap-name" does not exist
warning: "--mem" long option will be deprecated in favour of "--memory" in a future release.Please update any scripts, etc.
launch failed: Remote "snapcraft" is unknown or unreachable.                    
An error occurred with the instance when trying to launch with 'multipass': returned exit code 2.
Ensure that 'multipass' is setup correctly and try again.
```

and when I'm checking what's with multipass it shows plenty of Network access is disabled, i.e.

```
❯ snap logs multipass
2023-03-21T19:04:31-07:00 multipassd[911]: Could not update manifest: failed to download from 'https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/buildd/releases/bionic/release/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk.img': Network access is disabled.
2023-03-21T19:12:09-07:00 multipassd[911]: Error getting https://codeload.github.com/canonical/multipass-blueprints/zip/refs/heads/main: Network access is disabled. - trying cache.
2023-03-21T19:12:09-07:00 multipassd[911]: Cannot retrieve headers for https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/stable/current/ubuntu-core-16-amd64.img.xz: Network access is disabled.
2023-03-21T19:12:09-07:00 multipassd[911]: Could not update manifest: failed to download from 'https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/stable/current/ubuntu-core-16-amd64.img.xz': Network access is disabled.
2023-03-21T19:12:09-07:00 multipassd[911]: Cannot retrieve headers for https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/buildd/releases/bionic/release/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk.img: Network access is disabled.
2023-03-21T19:12:09-07:00 multipassd[911]: Could not update manifest: failed to download from 'https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/buildd/releases/bionic/release/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk.img': Network access is disabled.
2023-03-21T19:14:01-07:00 multipassd[911]: Cannot retrieve headers for https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/stable/current/ubuntu-core-16-amd64.img.xz: Network access is disabled.
2023-03-21T19:14:01-07:00 multipassd[911]: Could not update manifest: failed to download from 'https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/stable/current/ubuntu-core-16-amd64.img.xz': Network access is disabled.
2023-03-21T19:14:01-07:00 multipassd[911]: Cannot retrieve headers for https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/buildd/releases/bionic/release/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk.img: Network access is disabled.
2023-03-21T19:14:01-07:00 multipassd[911]: Could not update manifest: failed to download from 'https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/buildd/releases/bionic/release/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk.img': Network access is disabled.
```

I'm not sure if these logs are actually related as in the tutorial it says to use `core18` (which I used) and I also tried to use `core20`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was restarting multipass snap using

```
> sudo snap restart multipass
```

Got there by jumping:

- https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/an-error-occurred-with-the-instance-when-trying-to-launch-with-multipass-returned-exit-code-2-ensure-that-multipass-is-setup-correctly-and-try-again/30155/6
- https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/2534